# HTML table to excel using servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, servlets

I have an HTML table called "example1" and I have a bottom called "Export to excel". I need to export this HTML table to excel when I use this bottom. I need to use SERVELT, so my problem is: how can I export my HTML table "example1" to my servlet where I want to use the data of the HTML table to create an excel file? Is it possible to export an HTML table to my servlet AJAXCONTROLLER.java?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting you to use Jquery datatable to export data into excel directly from the client side.

Here is the link.
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html